# unable to call services in agGrid(Angular2) by cell renderer option

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using ag-Grid for displaying the list of user .If i edit the user details,then i want to click update button in grid to edit the corresponding user details.

This is coloumn header in ag_grid

```
 { headerName: 'Update', field: "update", width: 80, cellRenderer:this.updateRenderFunction}
```

i am using cell renderer

```
updateRenderFunction(params){
   var eSpan = document.createElement('button');
   eSpan.innerHTML = "Update";
    var data = params.node.data;

   eSpan.addEventListener('click',()=>{
                       //here i want to call service

  })

  return eSpan;

 }
```

Comment: You can find this answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395558/ag-gridangular-2-cannot-access-component-fields-in-cellrenderer/40395739#40395739

Answer (score 3):

Try this it worked for me...give bind(this) after updateRenderFunction like below.

```
{ headerName: 'Update', field: "update", width: 80, cellRenderer:this.updateRenderFunction.bind(this)}
```

Comment: I moved to primeng grid .Anyway thanks for your answer .