# Ag-grid(Angular 2) Cannot access component fields in CellRenderer

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm facing this issue while trying to call a service method on the click event of a button that is created using cellRenderer.

I'm using ag-grid with Angular2.

```
{ headerName: 'Update', field: "update", width: 80, cellRenderer : this.updateRecord }


updateRecord(params) {
    var eDiv = document.createElement('div');
    eDiv.innerHTML = '<span class="my-css-class"><button class="edit">Edit</button></span>';
    var eButton = eDiv.querySelectorAll('.edit')[0];
    eButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.myService.getAll().subscribe(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
    });
    return eDiv;
  }
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'getAll' of undefined
```

Also, I'm not able to access any of my Component variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

cellRenderer is in different context, so `this` is not accessible in `updateRecord` function.

You need to initialize `context` parameter in `gridOptions` and use it in `params` object.

set `context` in your `gridOptions` object in this way

```
this.gridOptions.context = {
            myService: this.myService
        }
```

Your `myService` will be available in `context` property.

```
updateRecord(params) {
    var eDiv = document.createElement('div');
    eDiv.innerHTML = '<span class="my-css-class"><button class="edit">Edit</button></span>';
    var eButton = eDiv.querySelectorAll('.edit')[0];
    eButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      params.context.myService.getAll().subscribe(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
    });
    return eDiv;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly fine.